# Issue with do-while loop, but can't seem to find it

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, do-while, continue

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code. If the user enters a negative integer, the program should keep telling the user to enter a positive until he does. I think it's the logic inside my do-while loop, but not sure.

[image: Something is def wrong.]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scratch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int firstN = 0;
    int secondN = 0;
    boolean isNumber = false;
    boolean isNumPos = false;

    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");

    do {
      if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        firstN = input.nextInt();
        isNumber = true;
      }
      if (firstN > 0) {
        isNumPos = true;
        isNumber = true;
        break;
      } else { 
        isNumPos = false;
        isNumber = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        input.next();
        continue;
      }
    } while (!(isNumber) || !(isNumPos));

    System.out.print("Enter another positive integer: ");
    do {
      if (input.hasNextInt()) {
        secondN = input.nextInt();
        isNumber = true;
      }
      if (secondN > 0) {
        isNumPos = true;
        isNumber = true;
      } else {
        isNumPos = false;
        isNumber = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
        input.next();
      }

    } while (!(isNumber) || !(isNumPos));

    System.out.println("The GCD of " + firstN + " and " + secondN + " is " + gCd(firstN, secondN));
  }

  public static int gCd(int firstN, int secondN) {
    if (secondN == 0) {
      return firstN;
    } else
      return gCd(secondN, firstN % secondN);
  }
}
```

Comment: `} while (!isNumber && !isNumPos);`...

Comment: Why not just use a single control variable `badInput=true` before the loop, and then report with a `continue` whenever you see a bad situation? if not number, "this is not a number" + `continue`. Let the `while(badInput)` do the rest. if number but negative, "please enter positive number" + `continue`. Again, let the `while(badInput)` do the rest. Once you run out of bad cases, you can set your `badInput` to false and you'll exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use && instead of || like this:

```
  } while (!isNumber && !isNumPos);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if this would be easier? :)

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numberOne = 0;
    int numberTwo = 0;

    boolean flag = true;

    System.out.println("Enter a positive number: ");
    numberOne = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter another positive number: ");
    numberTwo = input.nextInt();

    while (flag) {

        if (numberOne > 0 && numberTwo > 0) {
            flag = false;
        } else if (numberOne <= 0) {
            System.out.println("First number was invalid, please enter a positive number: ");
            numberOne = input.nextInt();
            flag = true;
        } else if (numberTwo <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Second number was invalid, please enter a positive number: ");
            numberTwo = input.nextInt();
            flag = true;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Your numbers were " + numberOne + " and " + numberTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked your code a little. There are easier ways to do this however.

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    firstN = input.nextInt();
    isNumber = true;

  if (firstN > 0) {
    isNumPos = true;
    isNumber = true;
    break;
  } else { 
    isNumPos = false;
    isNumber = false;
    continue;
  }
} while (!(isNumber) || !(isNumPos));


do {
    System.out.print("Enter another positive integer: ");
    secondN = input.nextInt();
    isNumber = true;

  if (secondN > 0) {
    isNumPos = true;
    isNumber = true;
  } else {
    isNumPos = false;
    isNumber = false;
  }

} while (!(isNumber) || !(isNumPos));
```